# Client thread hang emulation blocks server from accepting any I/O for the time client is set to wait

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, client

As the topic suggests I have a server and some clients. 
The server accepts I/O connections concurrently (no queueing in socket connections) but I have this troubling issue and I do not know how to bypass it!
If I force a client to throw an `I/O Exception` the server detects it and terminates the client thread correctly (verified from Task Manager (Windows) and System Monitor (Ubuntu) ). But If I emulate an I/O that is "hanging" like 
**i.e.**
 `Thread.sleep(60*1000);`
or

`private static Object lock = new Object();`

```
synchronized(lock) {
   while (true) {
      try {
         lock.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         /* Foo */
      }
   }
}
```

then all subsequent I/O operations (connection & data transfer) seem to block or wait until the "hanging" client is terminated. The applications makes use of the `ExecutorService` so if the "hanging" client does not complete the operations in the suggested time limit then the task will time out and the client is forced to exit. The subsequent "blocked" I/Os will resume but I wonder why the server doesn't accept any I/O connections or performs any I/O operations when a client "hangs"?

**NOTE:**The client threading takes place in the server main like this:

```
while (true) { 
   accept client connection;
   submit client task;
          ||
         \  /
          \/ 
   // ExecutorService here in the form 
   // spService.submit(new Callable<Tuple<String[], BigDecimal[]>>() { 
   // ... code ... }}).get(taskTimeout, taskTimeUnit);
   check task result & perform cleanup if result is null;
   otherwise continue;
}
```

Comment: What I/O is synchronous?   Obviously not the socket I/O which I assume is one socket per client.  Also, are you using a fixed size `ExecutorService`?  Are you running out of handler threads?

Comment: It sounds like you have single threaded executor.  How are you creating the ExecutorService?

Comment: @Gray I know before runtime the maximum number of clients so yes I am using a fixed size `ExecutorService` but does it matter? I mean this could not be the problem since from start I am testing a few client threads.

@JohnHaager 
Declaration is `private static volatile spService;` and it is called inside a method via this `return spService.submit(new Callable<Tuple<String[], BigDecimal[]>>() { ... }).get(taskTimeout, taskTimeUnit);`

Comment: To be clear, I do use `ServerSocket` and `Socket` for channels and `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for I/O. I also do create new `Socket`s and `ObjectInputStream`s and `ObjectOutputStream`s when a client connects. Should I use asynchronous I/O or does my problem lie elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the source of my problems! 
I do use one thread-per-client model but I run my tests locally i.e. in the same machine which means all of them have the same IP!
 So each client is assigned the same IP with the server! I guess that this leaves server and clients to differ only in port number but since each client is mapped to a different localport for each server connection then the server shouldn't block. I have confirmed that each client and server use different I/Os (compared references) and I wrap their sockets using `<Input/Output>Stream`s to `BufferedReader`s & `PrintWriter`s but still when a client hangs all other clients hang too (so maybe the I/O channels are indeed the same???)!
I will test this on another machine and check the results back with you! :)

**EDIT:** Confirmed the erratic behaviour. It seems that even with remote clients if one hangs the other clients seem to hang too! :/
Don't know but I am determined to fix this. It's just that it's pretty weird since I am pretty sure I use one thread-per-client (I/Os differ, client sockets differ, IPs seem to be not a problem, I even map each client in the server to a localport of my choice ...)
May be I'll switch to NIO if I don't find a solution soon enough.

**SOLUTION**: Solved the problem!
 It seemed that the `ExecutorService` had to be run in a seperate thread otherwise if an I/O in a client blocked, all I/Os would block!
 That's strange given the fact that I've tried both an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(<nThreads>);` and `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` and the client actions (aka I/Os) should take place in a new Thread for each client.
In any case, I used a method and wrapped the calls so each client instace would use a `final ExecutorService baseWorker = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` and created a new Thread explicitly each time using `<Thread instance>.start();` so each thread would run in the background :)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem :

This may very well indicate that your server ACCEPTS client connections concurrently, however, it only handles these connections synchronously.  That means that even if a million clients connect, successfully, at any given time, if anyone of them takes a long time (or hangs), it will hold up the others.

The TEST:

To verify this : I would toggle the amount of time a client takes to connect by adding Thread.sleep statments(1000) in your clients.

Expected result :

I believe you will see that even adding a single Thread.sleep(1000) statement in your client delays all other connecting clients by 1000.

Comment: That's my problem as I said! If a client hangs for a minute all clients will have to wait! So, I am asking what's wrong with what I am doing as far as application logic is concerned? Should I explicitly create new Threads via Runnable methods? Because I have done that too and it does exactly the same thing!

Comment: Well, it should not. If a thread per client model is used, each client handling runs independently and if one client asks for a sleep(1000) call, (or some blocking I/O), only that one client should wait.   I often use this model for exactly that reason - protocols that specify waits or delays are trivial in one-thread-per-client, messy in asynchronous, (state-machines, timer queues etc).